# Vim custom command: run a command in shell followed by a command in vim

Tags: vim

I'm writing a simple command for an operation I do quite often in vim:

`command! EslintFix !./node_modules/.bin/eslint --fix %`

This will change the file I'm currently working on, so I'd like to reload the file in the same command but I'm not sure how to follow the shell command with the Vim command `e%` to reload the current file. If I write this:

`command! EslintFix !./node_modules/.bin/eslint --fix % | e%`

Vim ends up running `e%` in the shell instead of Vim.

How can I write a custom command like this where I want to execute something in the shell followed by executing a Vim command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option #1 (using `system()`):

```
command! EslintFix call system('./node_modules/.bin/eslint --fix ' . fnameexpand('%:p:S')) | e%
```

Option #2 (using `execute`):

```
command! EslintFix execute '!./node_modules/.bin/eslint --fix %' | e%
```